# subclass UILabel to have letter spacing doesn't work with accent letter

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uifont

i have found this code here on SO that help me to have a letter spacing in a UILabel, this is the code:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSelectFont (context, [self.font.fontName cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], self.font.pointSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(context, 2);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
CGAffineTransform myTextTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.f, -1.f );

CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, myTextTransform);

// draw 1 but invisbly to get the string length.
CGPoint p =CGContextGetTextPosition(context);
float centeredY = (self.font.pointSize + (self.frame.size.height- self.font.pointSize)/2)-2;
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, centeredY, [self.text cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], [self.text length]);
CGPoint v =CGContextGetTextPosition(context);

// calculate width and draw second one.
float width = v.x - p.x;
float destX = 0;

// calculate X position based on alignment
if([self textAlignment] == UITextAlignmentLeft){
    destX = 0;
}else if([self textAlignment] == UITextAlignmentCenter){
    destX = (self.frame.size.width- width)/2;
}else if([self textAlignment] == UITextAlignmentRight){
    destX = self.frame.size.width - width;
}
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [self.textColor CGColor]);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, destX, centeredY, [self.text cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], [self.text length]);
}
```

the problem is that with the accent letter like èàòé the uilabel is empty, how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably using the wrong encoding when loading the font. Try changing this line:

```
CGContextSelectFont (context, [self.font.fontName cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], self.font.pointSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
```

to use this encoding instead:

```
    CGContextSelectFont (context, [self.font.fontName cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], self.font.pointSize, kCGEncodingFontSpecific);
```

And then where you output the string you are using this encoding `NSASCIIStringEncoding` which according to Apple docs most definitely does NOT include the characters you want. So even if you read in the character set using the correct encoding your not going to output it with that.

Because from Apple Docs the encoding your using to output the string:

```
 NSASCIIStringEncoding
 Strict 7-bit ASCII encoding within 8-bit chars; ASCII values 0…127 only.
 Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
```

Comment: Well then better find out what the correct encoding is for the font your loading and use that. But it is very likely an encoding mismatch

Comment: These methods have been deprecated. Use CoreText as of iOS7

Comment: Well to be more precise CGContextSelectFont is deprecated in iOS 7, NOT cStringUsingEncoding: which was actually the answer/solution.